# User Interface quality issue with some programs on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, user-interface, ubuntu-unity

As the title explains, i have a weird issue with the UI of some programs on windows 7 (Google chrome & unity). Basically the UI looks deformed. Tool bars, fonts etc have irregular shapes to a certain extent.

[image]

What's causing that problem and how can i fix it? And why does it occur only with those 2 programs and not the rest? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

90%+ of UI-related problems in Windows Vista and 7 are due to AERO.

To test your app without interference, open a cmd and type
net stop themes
After you study the effects on your applications, you can type 'net start themes' to reload everything.
Later, you can tweak the windows GUI to fit your needs.

Other things that influence that are aspect ratios (even a difference from 16:10 to 16:9 is critical) and video card drivers (and their configurations).

Comment: It was a video card driver issue. Uninstalled it, then used DDU (display driver uninstaller) in Safe Mode,and reinstalled my  driver,everything is ok now,thanks.